# How can I make an iframe clickthrough to base html

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm working on an iframe where I'm trying to overlay the iframe on top of a web page. The iframe is a floating button that remains on the bottom right of the webpage no matter where the user is on the page. The issue I'm having is that while scrolling works perfectly, the buttons and links on the base html page (where the iframe is called) are not functional anymore. The code for the iframe is here:

```html
<iframe src="ka.html" title="KA"
        style=" padding: 0px; margin: 10px 20px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; overflow: visible; opacity: 1; border: 0px; z-index: 999998; transition-duration: 250ms; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); transition-property: opacity, top, bottom; right: 0px;"
        height="100%" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

How can I get the base layer functionality working? I really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Are you sire your iframe is not covering the whole viewport? Also, unless you really need this to be an iframe, I strongly suggest you just absolute position that element instead of using an iframe

Comment: Sadly this is for another webpage so iframe is my best option right now. That means I sadly cant use absolute position without messing the formatting of the rest of the webpage. Any ideas?

Comment: Then my other point is important. If the iframe is taking up the whole viewport ( but is largely transparent with something im one corner) then it's going to swallow all the events.  Unless you control that page as well, there is basically nothing you can do about it other than put your content above the iframe